# Javascript-made Divs not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div (lets call it fatherDiv) with relative position and a fixed width and height.

I send this object to a javascript function (init) that creates 3 overlaying divs and puts them as fatherDiv's childs. Yet, these 3 overlaying divs are not displaying properly.

I want to have this outcome:

[image]

I'm trying to achieve this by using these javascript functions:

```
   function fabDiv(width, z) {

    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.setAttribute("height", "200px");
    element.setAttribute("width", width.toString()+"px");
    element.setAttribute("position", "absolute");
    element.setAttribute("top", "0");
    element.setAttribute("left", "0");
    element.setAttribute("z-index", z.toString());

    return element;
}
function init(container, /*img1, img2, img3,*/ interval) {

    div1 = fabDiv(294, 3);
    div2 = fabDiv(265, 2);
    div3 = fabDiv(235, 1);

    container.appendChild(div1);
    container.appendChild(div2);
    container.appendChild(div3);

    div3.setAttribute("background-color", "lightblue");
    div2.setAttribute("background-color", "blue");
    div1.setAttribute("background-color", "darkblue");
}
```

Any advice is welcome. Thanks :)

PS: When i F12 on chrome to inspect the html elements created, i can see the divs in code but the little tooltip shows that they have no height (0px).

Comment: `float:left` has no meaning when using absolute positioning, also background-color is a style not an attribute `div.style.backgroundColor="#0F0";`. And you will want to switch the z index order, the larger the number the higher in the stack they are

Comment: woops! didnt erase that after testing to see if that fixed it. mb!

Comment: If so, then so is the z-index, right?

Comment: Changing it all to this did the trick. Thanks for pointing out the fact that attributes =/= style properties. :)


element.setAttribute("style", "background-color:"+color+";height:200px;width:" + width.toString() + "px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:" + z.toString());

Comment: you do not have to use the .toString() function it is automatically called when needed to convert a number to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/leqov/6/edit)**

```
function fabDiv(width, bgCol) {  
    var el = document.createElement("div");  
    el.style.height = "200px";
    el.style.width = width+"px";
    el.style.position = "absolute";
    el.style.backgroundColor = bgCol;  
    return el;
}

function init(container, /*img1, img2, img3,*/ interval) {
    container.appendChild( fabDiv(294, "lightblue") );
    container.appendChild( fabDiv(265, "blue") );
    container.appendChild( fabDiv(235, "darkblue") );
}

var cont = document.getElementById('container');
init(cont);
```

Another way to do it:

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/leqov/5/edit)**

```
function CSS( el, prop, val ){
   if(!val && typeof prop == "object" ) for(var key in prop) el.style[key] = prop[key];
   else el.style[prop] = val;
   return el; 
}

function fabDiv( obj ) {
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  CSS(el, {height:"200px", width:obj.width+"px", position:"absolute", backgroundColor:obj.backgroundColor
  });
  document.getElementById(obj.appendTo).appendChild(el);
  return el;
}

function init() {
  fabDiv({width:294, backgroundColor:"lightblue", appendTo:'container'});
  fabDiv({width:265, backgroundColor:"blue", appendTo:'container'});
  fabDiv({width:235, backgroundColor:"darkblue", appendTo:'container'});
}
```

Comment: style.float = "left" is a new one on me. Please explain.

Comment: I think that one is not needed (I edited it out once i thought it was there in the OP). My bad i guess

Comment: @J_Ocampo no it's not needed it was a copy-paste left-in. Added also another nice example.